# System with base $5$ - difference of importance is even

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, number-systems

I want to show that all non zero positive integers that are multiple of $3$ and have exactly two non zero digits in their representation in system of base $5$, have even difference of importance at these two digits, only if these are “$1$” and “$2$” or “$2$” and “$4$” or “$3$” and “$3$”.

Importance is the power of the base that correspond to the digit.

So do we have to check all differences of pairs $(1,2)$, $(1,3)$, $(1,4)$, $(2,3)$, $(2,4)$, $(3,4)$ to get that only at the given ones the difference is even?

Let  $x=\sum_{i=0}^N5^id_i$. Since it is a multiple of $3$ we have that  $\left (\sum_{i=0}^N5^id_i\right ) \pmod 3=0$

If $d_i=1$ then we have that $5^id_i\pmod 3 \equiv 5^i\pmod 3 \equiv 2^i\pmod 3\equiv (-1)^i\pmod 3$.

If $d_i=2$ then we have that $5^id_i\pmod 3 \equiv 5^i\cdot 2\pmod 3  \equiv 2^i\cdot 2\pmod 3  \equiv 2^{i+1}\pmod 3 \equiv (-1)^{i+1}\pmod 3 $.

If $d_i=3$ then we have that $5^id_i\pmod 3 \equiv 5^i\cdot 3\pmod 3 \equiv 0$.

If $d_i=4$ then we have that $5^id_i\pmod 3 \equiv 5^i\cdot 4\pmod 3 \equiv 5^i\cdot 1\pmod 3 \equiv 5^i \pmod 3 \equiv 2^i \pmod 3 \equiv (-1)^i\pmod 3$.

Considering all differences we check which pair has an even result :

We check the pair $d_i=1$ and $d_i=2$ then we get $[(-1)^i-(-1)^{i+1}]\pmod 3\equiv \pm 2$.

We check the pair $d_i=1$ and $d_i=3$ then we get $[(-1)^i-0]\pmod 3\equiv (-1)^i$.

We check the pair $d_i=1$ and $d_i=4$ then we get $[(-1)^i-(-1)^{i}]\pmod 3\equiv 0$.

We check the pair $d_i=2$ and $d_i=3$ then we get $[(-1)^{i+1}-0]\pmod 3\equiv (-1)^{i+1}$.

We check the pair $d_i=2$ and $d_i=4$ then we get $[(-1)^{i+1}-(-1)^{i}]\pmod 3\equiv \pm 2$.

We check the pair $d_i=3$ and $d_i=4$ then we get $[0-(-1)^{i}]\pmod 3\equiv (-1)^{i+1}$.

Is that correct so far?

Comment: I am astonished and embarrassed that several mathSE reviewers chose to downvote your question.  I have upvoted it from -3 to -2.  You showed a great deal of effort in working your conjecture and showing your work.

Comment: Without delving too deeply into the question, it seems to me that your assertion revolves around the fact that $25 \equiv 1\pmod{3}$, and so numbers of the form $25^k \equiv 1\pmod{3}$ while numbers of the form $5 \times 25^k \equiv 2\pmod{3}.$  I then notice that in each of the ordered pairs $(x,y)$ that you identified, $(1,2), (2,4), (3,3)$, you then have that $x + y \equiv 0\pmod{3}$.  I could easily be mistaken about the pertinence of this analysis.  I did not scrutinize your question very closely.  I was too busy emotionally reacting to the embarrassing anonymous downvotes.

Comment: This is a perfectly good question. Why the downvote?

Comment: Thank you!! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our number has only 2 digits in base 5, we are effectively looking for solutions to,

$$a5^r+b5^s \equiv 0 \mod 3$$

Because $5\equiv 2 \mod 3$ we can divide it out and rewrite it as,

$$a2^{r-s} + b \equiv 0 \mod 3$$

Now since we have the restriction that the 'difference of importance' forces $r-s \equiv 0 \mod 2$, we have by Fermat's little theorem that we can replace this in the exponent.

$$a + b \equiv 0 \mod 3$$

Now we simply have to check which nonzero digits in base $5$ satisfy this congruence modulo $3$.

Since $1 \equiv 4 \mod 3$ we see that $1+2 \equiv 4+2 \equiv 0 \mod 3$ and further we check $3+3\equiv 0 \mod 3$ exhausts all possibilities, which completes the proof.

Comment: By Fermat's little theorem we have that $a^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod p$. Do we use that for $p=2$ ? Or for $p=3$ ? I got stuck right now.

Comment: Do we have that $r-s=2k$ and so $2^{r-s}=2^{2k}=(2^2)^k\equiv 1\pmod 3$ from Fermat's little theorem ?

Comment: We use $p=3$ here and your second comment is correct that's what happens; sorry for being a bit too terse! If you have more questions feel free to ask.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!! :-)

Comment: You're welcome.